# How to center an image over 2 divs

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to achieve something but in vain. I have put the image below, it's worth a thousand words.

[image: Current]

Basically I'm trying to center div 3, which is in div 2, between div 1 and 2 exactly to achieve the following result

[image: After]

Now, here's my HTML and CSS code:

**HTML**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide">
        <!-- 1. -->
    </div>

    <div id="rightSide">
        <!-- 2. -->
        <div id="circle">
            <!-- 3. Contains the image -->
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#leftSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#rightSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:left
    background-color: red;
}

#circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    margin-left: 30px;
    background-color: black;
}
```

I don't have a clear idea on how to achieve it. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Can be done with `position:absolute;`(along with the positions as shown below) to the `#circle` and `position:relative` to the `#container`.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/a081j6bv/1/

```
#container{
 position:relative;
}

#circle{
 position:absolute;
 left:0;
 top:0;
 bottom:0;
 right:0;
 margin:auto; 
}
```

Comment: I've tried it but in my actual code, the circle div has several images one below the other. Now when I apply this it work and I see 1 image at the center but the other images disappear. Why?

Comment: This solution is specific to this question. Can you please post your actual code so that I can review?

Answer (score 2):

Assuming that you are going to have the "circle" div set as a static height/width you can do it by positioning it absolutely 50% left and top and then set a negative margin to half the size of the circle div.

**HTML:**

```
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide">
        <!-- 1. -->
    </div>

    <div id="rightSide">
        <!-- 2. -->
    </div>

    <div id="circle">
        <!-- 3. Contains the image -->
    </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#container{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position:relative;
}

#leftSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#rightSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
}

#circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
    background-color: black;
    position:absolute;
    top:50%;
    left:50%;
    margin-top:-50px;
    margin-left:-50px;
}
```

## [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/duybLg12/)

Comment: I've tried it but in my actual code, the circle div has several images one below the other. Now when I apply this it work and I see 1 image at the center but the other images disappear. Why is it that case?

Comment: @nTuply because, as I mentioned, this solution will only work if the circle div has a static height and width like in your example. You would need to figure out how tall and wide the div is on your actual site and change the `margin-top` and `margin-left` values to be negative half the size of the div (`-50px` for both values from your example, since the div has a width and height of `100px`).

Answer (score 2):

You could always try using the [**CSS position property**](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_positioning.asp)?

**CSS**

```
#container{
width: 600px;
float: left;
padding: 0;
margin: 0 auto;
position:relative;
}

#leftSide{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float:left;
background-color: blue;
}

#rightSide{
width: 300px;
height: 300px;
float:left
background-color: red;
}

#circle{
width: 100px;
height: 100px;
margin-left: 30px;
background-color: black;
position:absolute;
top:/* VALUE GOES HERE */;
left:/* VALUE GOES HERE */;
}
```

`top:50px;` **drops** the element down 50px

`left:50px;` moves the element to the **right** 50px

Answer (score 1):

You need to give the `#container` a `relative` positioning and an `absolute` positioning to the circle.

```css
#container{
    width: 600px;
    float: left;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0 auto;
    position: relative;
}

#leftSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:left;
    background-color: blue;
}

#rightSide{
    width: 300px;
    height: 300px;
    float:right;
    background-color: red;
}

#circle{
    width: 100px;
    height: 200px;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top:0;
    bottom:0;
    margin: auto;
    background-color: black;
}
#circle img{
   width: 100px;
   height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide">
        <!-- 1. -->
    </div>

    <div id="rightSide">
        <!-- 2. -->
        <div id="circle">
            <!-- 3. Contains the image -->
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/lrg4uy5.jpg"/>
            <img src="http://i.imgur.com/RLKixQW.png"/>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I've tried it but in my actual code, the circle div has several images one below the other. Now when I apply this it work and I see 1 image at the center but the other images disappear. Why?

Answer (score 1):

According to your tastes and needs, you may choose one of the 4 following templates:

---

#### #1 Center circle using `position`, `top`, `bottom`, `left`, `right` and `margin` properties

```css
#container {
    height: 300px;
    /* prepare #container to center #circle */
    position: relative;
}
#leftSide {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#rightSide {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#circle {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    /* center #circle inside #container */
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    margin: auto;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide">
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### #2 Center circle using `position`, `top`, `left`, `margin-top` and `margin-left` properties

```css
#container {
    height: 300px;
    /* prepare #container to center #circle */
    position: relative;
}
#leftSide {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#rightSide {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#circle {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    /* center #circle inside #container */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    margin-top: -70px;
    margin-left: -70px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide">
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### #3 Center circle using `position`, `top`, `left` and `transform` properties

```css
#container {
    height: 300px;
    /* prepare #container to center #circle */
    position: relative;
}
#leftSide {
    background-color: blue;
    float: left;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#rightSide {
    background-color: red;
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    width: 50%;
}
#circle {
    background-color: black;
    border-radius: 50%;
    height: 140px;
    width: 140px;
    /* center #circle inside #container */
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="leftSide"></div>
    <div id="rightSide">
        <div id="circle"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

#### #4 Center circle using Flexbox

Note that the following HTML snippet is different from the previous ones.

```css
#container {
height: 300px;
background: linear-gradient(90deg, blue 50%, red 50%);
/* prepare #container to center #circle */
display: flex;
align-items: center;
justify-content: center;
}
#circle {
background-color: black;
border-radius: 50%;
height: 140px;
width: 140px;
}
```

```html
<div id="container">
    <div id="circle"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

hey guys i had the same problem as a beginner..so  to achieve the effect i had to set the container's position to relative and the image's position to absolute...works like magic
-ENJOY!